# Designing an audio amplifier, problems with bandpass filter

Tags: audio, circuit-design, filter, band-pass

I am trying to build a Audio amplifier for a university project, I think that most of my circuit is done but I have an issue with my filter as my sine signal is not symmetrical after filtering to eliminate the offset, Instead of having an interval of aprox. +-5V I get an interval of +5 -> -7. I have used 3 opamps for amplifying the signal and a potentiometer at the first one so that I can increase my interval to 8V(maximum that I need to output).

As my input data I have:

- Ai = 700µV
- Bandpass freq = 32 -> 512 Hz
- Ao = 5-8 V
- Rl = 40 Ohm

Below is the [circuit and simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk7Yg.jpg)(transient of 10ms w/ step of 10u)
I've tried using Chebyshev filter or a Active Butterworth Filter using some online calculators but I am getting from the computations two resistors with negative values and that's not ok.

[image: Schematic]

[image: schematic 2]

[image: Voltages over time]

Bode plot:

[image: Bode plot]

I've tried using a active band pass filter but that also didn't work out; I can provide the project if needed.

Comment: just a general recommendation: Analog Device's [Filter design tool](https://www.analog.com/designtools/en/filterwizard/) is actually excellent, and won't give you negative resistor values.

Comment: Oh, and get rid of the µ741 opamp. That is like the grand-grandfather of modern opamps and **really** shouldn't be used anymore when it comes to filtering. It's terrible.

Comment: Do you recommend any specific opamps? There's a set of opamps that were presented at univerisity(741, 771, 726)

Comment: Oh, these are all from the same generation. Seriously, a university should have access to better opamps – modern opamps cost insignificantly more than these dinosaurs. Hey, if you're a student, you might even ask Analog Devices to send you a free sample of their opamps :) Just use the Filter design tool that I've linked to above, and they will suggest an opamp that works with your frequencies, your supply and signal voltages, etc. You can also tell it to only use the most common capacitor and resistor values (E6 series / E12 series), so that you definitely find the right parts at university!

Comment: (I have to correct myself: there now seems to be an LMP771 op amp, that seems quite decent, sou you might want to use that one – but you'll have to check its datasheet to see whether it works for your voltages at all!)

Comment: Run an AC analysis, not transient, then you can look at all frequencies at once, not just one. Show a bode plot, not transient

Comment: Oh, also, your filter specification is incomplete: you specify a passband, but not a stop band and a stop band attenuation. We know what should go through, but you'll have to define where "nothing" should get through, and "how little" is actually "nothing". Oh, and an acceptable passband ripple would be necessary to have, too.

Comment: If you are going to run a transient analysis, run it for much longer than 10ms. I don't think your circuit has reached steady-state.

Comment: Note the DC offset of amp3 at t=0 it is approximately 1 V. The first amplifier has an input offset voltage that gets amplified by (20)^3

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is just a prototype so I do not have to build a physical prototype just to get it's simulated behavior. About the stop band and stop attenuation these were not given to us, it went like this "Design a audio amplifier and you these X,Y values, nothing more".

Comment: well, then why did you pick a band pass filter? Why 512 Hz? Why 32?

Comment: This filter specification, i.e. a -3dB point at 32 Hz and at 512 Hz, and no significant "holes" in between , will require you to use at least 5 stages of active filters, roughly estimating. So, that's easily 24 components that you'll have to use. Doesn't sound like a wise filter specification if you "don't actually care".

Comment: Personally, I'd even go with "building this 10th order, 5 stage filter as reliable analog filter is going to be so expensive and exhausting (in tuning it until it is just right, considering tolerances and everything), that I'd actually, honestly, go and just convert the signal to digital, filter it in software on a sufficiently fast microcontroller or PC, and convert it back to analog, even if that means one anti-aliasing filter, one ADC, one thing that does the computation, one DAC and one reconstruction filter".

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Got it [here](https://imgur.com/a/hauLMA6).
(at) MarcusMüller I thought it would be more appropriate, regarding your question from ~10 minutes ago. Thanks for all the tips, the link you have provided computed a solution that seems viable and I am now implementing it, sorry for late reply but I am stressing over this.

Comment: @Jewlanu so, that bode plot looks about what I'd expect from a single-stage passive RC-CR bandpass filter. What's wrong with it?

Comment: From my knowledge, the output signal should be fed back to the amplifier, as a negative feedback. This is where you adjust the gain and further it acts as P controller, thus trying to eliminate the nonlinearity. Your proposed amp is very bad it terms of distortion.

Comment: (also, by the way, why do you have the two fixed amplification blocks? They seem super unnecessary and could be absorbed in the first, adjustable amplification block.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller after resizing(again)my passive RC filter the output signal looks quite right, but now I want to try the filter that Analog provided as a solution. Suddenly things started to workout :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've added those so that I can get the necessary output from the amplification block, I haven't tried using just one so I went with the flow and getting recommendations from multiple  parts lead to that.

Comment: um, but you're the *engineer* here. You're the one designing the amplification stage, and you're supposed to be understanding at least amplification in a non-inverting opamp amplifier configuation (seriously, this was first semester stuff for me) – and unless you have a good reason, it makes no sense – you only amplify your 700 µV signal to 8 V, so that's not even a factor of 15. All you get by having more stages is more room for tolerances to creep in and ruin the day. Not knowing how to build a good filter from the top of your head – I share that problem. Not being able to amplify by <15…